# InvocationTargetException storing files with appengine-gcs-client-0.5 dev_appserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using [appengine-gcs-client-0.5](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/tools/appengine-gcs-client/0.5/) and seeing InvocationTargetExceptions in my dev_appserver when calling [GcsService.createOrReplace](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsService#createOrReplace(com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename,%20com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions)) and [GcsOutputChannel.close](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsOutputChannel#close()).

It seems like the call to storeBlob does not have the appropriate permission, as the appserver gets an AccessControlException in com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.FileBlobStorage.storeBlob:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/tmp/1440435923000-0/encoded_gs_key:<some key>" "write")
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

appengine-gcs-client-0.5 removed a dependency on the deprecated Files API, but the SDK does not yet acquire the necessary permissions to store files the BlobStorage service.  As a workaround until the next SDK version is released, you can pass a flag to configure a memory-backed store for the Blobstore service like so:

dev_appserver.sh --jvm_flag=-Dblobstore.no_storage=true

This is only necessary for the dev_appserver - production applications will not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i was going crazy with this.

Comment: Well, this seems to be the only way to get it working for now, but as soon as de devserver is restarted the memory-backed stored files goes down and impossible to read.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with AE 1.9.27 (which is now available) there is no longer a need for the jvm_flag (it should just work).