# Access denied while saving to Google Cloud Storage using Java client api on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I following the Google App Engine example for saving data to Google Cloud Storage at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/java/example/src/com/google/appengine/demos/LocalExample.java#L79

But I keep getting the following exception:

```
 Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\...\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\encoded_gs_key:L2dzL2NvZGVhdmVuZ2Vycy5hcHBzcG90LmNvbS90ZXN0MTQ6anM" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.FileBlobStorage.storeBlob(FileBlobStorage.java:46)
    ... 57 more
```

I have no idea what is causing this.

I am using the following method to save the data:

```
private final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory
      .createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());

  /**
   * Writes the provided object to the specified file using Java serialization.
   * One could use this same technique to write many objects, or with another
   * format such as Json or XML or just a DataOutputStream.
   *
   * Notice at the end closing the ObjectOutputStream is not done in a finally
   * block. See below for why.
   */
  private void writeObjectToFile(GcsFilename fileName, String content)
      throws IOException {
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName,
        GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(
        Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
    oout.writeChars(content);
    oout.close();
  }
```

Here is the code for calling that function:

```
GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename("xxx.appspot.com", id + ":" + file);
          writeObjectToFile(filename, data);
```

Comment: You have a problem with file and folder permissions. Please check whether the user which tries to access the given files or folders has the right to do so.

Comment: I am running the server from eclipse. I tried starting eclipse as "Admin" and that didn't work. I am using the Blobstore API with the Images service to store user uploaded images on Google Cloud Storage and that all works fine, and I assume that is saving to the same folder. Also, the local version of the datastore is stored in that same folder as well... so I am confused as to how its a permissions problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It used to work and now started getting this error. Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: If you still have this issue, I managed to solve it by upgrading appengine to version 1.9.27 after seeing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236614/invocationtargetexception-storing-files-with-appengine-gcs-client-0-5-dev-appser/32236631